# What is the best way to list all the name in List<String> from List<MyData>

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Suppose I have a class MyData.

```
public class Mydata(){
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Now my list will be having 100 MyData objects and I want to extract only the names and prepare a new list:

```
List<String> nameList;
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the best option:

```
for (Mydata mydata : mydataList){
    nameList.add(mydata.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can use stream() and map() for a much more concise and clear variant:

```
data.stream().map(Mydata::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here as a full program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    static class Mydata
    {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public String getName() {return name;}
        public int getAge() {return age;}

        public Mydata(String name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Mydata> data = Arrays.asList(new Mydata[] {new Mydata("Tom",10),new Mydata("Mary",20)});
        //map(m->m.name) also works
        List<String> nameList = data.stream().map(Mydata::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(nameList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care the sorting...

```
for (Mydata mydata : mydataList){
    nameList.add(mydata.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java 8...

```
List<Mydata> mydatas = ...
List<String> names =
    mydatas.stream().map(mydata -> mydata.name).collect(Collectors.toList())
```